# Upload a project to github C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github

I created a repository on GitHub called Map.

Then went to my GitHub projects folder and successfully cloned it to that folder. It only had a readme file.

Then I copied and pasted everything in my Map directory under Visual Studio projects into my GitHub Map directory.

Then I did the `github push -u origin master` line.

Then it said everything up-to-date which i think means there was no changes to add, but I did add my project to the GitHub Map folder so it should have had changes?

Am I going about this correctly?

I also did all the other command line commands required I believe. I first want to point out why it might say "up-to-date" and ask, do I copy and paste my VS project into the GitHub project folder, to add the project?

Comment: Please use proper capitalization in the future, i.e. use "I believe" and not "i believe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably says `Everything up-to-date` when you `github push -u origin master` because it sounds like you haven't actually made any commits in your local repo to push to your remote yet.

Before you push source code to a remote repo, you must first add and commit it to your local repository:

```bash
git add . # Add everything in the current directory (".")
git commit
git push origin master # Now you can push.
```

Also, it's unusual that you would keep your local repo directory separate from your working directory for Visual Studio. A typical setup would be to just initialize a Git repo directly in your working directory:

```bash
cd <your-visual-studio-project-folder>
git init
git add . # Add everything in the current directory (".")
git commit

git remote add origin <url-for-your-remote>
git fetch origin

# Rebase your local root commit onto the remote root commit
git rebase --onto origin/master --root

# Now you can push to your remote
git push origin master
```

Finally, I ***highly recommend*** that you read the [***FREE*** online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), especially chapters 1-3 and 6-6.5, it will help you with most of your future Git problems.